# AWS Cognito doesn't refresh user attributes from identity provider when access token expires

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito

We have setup Cognito user pool with AzureAD identity provider. We have added some custom attributes with attributes mapping and make them all writeable and readable. User is able to login and we see those custom attributes in issued token, so everything seems to work correctly.

But... when we change some attributes on AzureAD side then those changes are not reflected on Cognito user pool attributes and therefore are not reflected in claims of the following access tokens. In order to force Cognito to sync user data with AzureAD user has to sign out and sign in. And since refresh token is valid for 30 days by default it means that potentially user may have out-of-date claims for quite long time.

That's the huge issue from security perspective. Imagine scenario when some user's permissions (expressed as claims) are removed on AzureAD side and for next few days user still have those permissions because that change is not reflected in tokens issued by AWS Cognito.

So how to fix this issue? How to force Cognito to update user attributes from identity provider each time access token expires? Clearing refresh token on browser site is not a solution. I cannot find anything on AWS documentation about it (or basically anywhere else), there is also no synchronize settings on user pools, etc.

Comment: You mentioned that "Clearing refresh token on browser site is not a solution". Would setting the refresh token expiration to 1 day help? I know it's not the same as real-time, but at least it's better than 30 days. Also is there a user pool attribute that you could maybe map to check the user's permissions in AD? I'm not too familiar with OAuth so I'm not sure how this is usually handled. Perhaps you could also check out Amazon Cognito Sync. Most of the documentation is about updating user info from the client side but maybe it could be leveraged differently to support your use case.

Comment: @Konrad Gąska Did you manage to fix this problem?